# Comparar linhas as linhas entre dois quadro de dados?

Tags: r, data.frame

Considerando:

```
q1 <- data.frame(COD = 1:5, CLAS=letters[1:5])
q2 <- data.frame(COD = c(25,1,31,3,2), CLAS=c(45,letters[1],100,letters[3],letters[10]))
```

Preciso saber quais as linhas que são comuns entre os quadro de dados, levando-se em conta que a linha toda deve ser igual. 
Existe alguma função que retorne o índice de q1 para q2, ou vice-versa?

No caso de `q1` para `q2`, as linhas 1 e 3 estão em 2 e 4. Ou as linhas 2 e 4 de `q2` equivalem a 1 e 3 de `q1`.

Como posso realizar esta comparação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se você precisa dos índices. Se bastar um data.frame com as linhas em comum, uma solução alternativa é usar o `inner_join`:

```
> q1 <- data.frame(COD = 1:5, CLAS=letters[1:5], stringsAsFactors = F)
> q2 <- data.frame(COD = c(25,1,31,3,2), CLAS=c(45,letters[1],100,letters[3],letters[10]), stringsAsFactors = F)
> library(dplyr)
> inner_join(q1, q2)
Joining by: c("COD", "CLAS")
  COD CLAS
1   1    a
2   3    c
```

Por padrão o `inner_join` usa todas as colunas que possuem o mesmo nome nos dois `data.frames`, se você não quisesse usar todas, poderia usar o argumento `by`. Leia mais em: `help("join")`.

---

Claro que você pode adaptar este código para guardar os índices das duplicações de cada um dos conjuntos de dados, mas aí o código já não fica tão elegante.

```
> inner_join(
+   q1 %>% mutate(id_q1 = 1:nrow(.)), 
+   q2 %>% mutate(id_q2 = 1:nrow(.))
+   )
Joining by: c("COD", "CLAS")
  COD CLAS id_q1 id_q2
1   1    a     1     2
2   3    c     3     4
```

Comment: Muito bom. ... Valeu

Answer (score 4):

Este código abaixo funciona bem. Imagino que seja rápido mesmo se os teus data frames sejam um pouquinho grandes.

```
q1 <- data.frame(COD = 1:5, CLAS=letters[1:5])
q2 <- data.frame(COD = c(25,1,31,3,2), CLAS=c(45,letters[1],100,letters[3],letters[10]))

q  <- rbind(q1, q2)

duplicados <- duplicated(q)

which(duplicados==TRUE)-dim(q1)[1]
```